# How can I retrive json data from php?

Tags: php, json

Currently i'm using this php script to retrieve json data:

```
 // Execute  call
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.flairwin.com/get_json.php');

// Decode the JSON feed
$json = json_decode($data);

 print_r($json);
```

the json returned from get_json.php is :

```
 {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4,
  "e": 5
 }
```

How can I process this in my php script?
`print_r($json)` do not show nothing on my browser.

Comment: what did you got in $data try to var_dump it. if its decoded perfectly you can access each element by simply $joson->a; which is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r"); # This part is from the Docs
$json = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $json .= fread($handle, 1024);
}
fclose($handle);

$decoded_array = json_decode($json);
```

Please note that no change in the php.ini is required, which could prevent attacking vectors being employed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Execute  call
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.flairwin.com/get_json.php');

// Decode the JSON feed
$json = json_decode($data, true);

print_r($json);
```

Output:

```
  Array ( 
   [a] => 1 
   [b] => 2 
   [c] => 3 
   [d] => 4 
   [e] => 5 
  )
```

**allow_url_fopen** = 1 in php.ini ?

Comment: tanks!but what i can't do here is $json->a